# fb integration should not pass read permission (email)

Tags: android, facebook

**When i testing integration in my app then it will completely work on samsung and xiomi device but in other device it'll give following errors so is this api level issue or any other, errors are following:**

Here is my code:

```
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}
```

04-24 10:25:41.822: W/com.facebook.Session(26010): Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or manage authorization
04-24 10:25:41.822: I/Timeline(26010): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.facebook.katana time:6217066
04-24 10:25:41.862: D/Facebook-Util(26010): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?format=json
04-24 10:25:42.482: D/Profile(26010): {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
04-24 10:25:42.482: W/System.err(26010): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
04-24 10:25:42.482: W/System.err(26010):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
04-24 10:25:42.482: W/System.err(26010):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
04-24 10:25:42.482: W/System.err(26010):    at com.h3ck.choicemobileno.welcome$5.onComplete(welcome.java:217)
04-24 10:25:42.482: W/System.err(26010):    at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)

if plz any've solution of this then plz post it'll be appreciate....

Comment: Please add your `welcome.java` file around line number 26.

Comment: have you define facebook login activity in ur project AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: my fb login activity in my sign in page which is already in manifest file.